# Emgu - How to extract the images likely to represent an icon or control from a screenshot?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, ocr, emgucv

I'm working on an experimental project in which the challenge is to identify and extract an image of the icon or control that the user is has clicked on/touched. The method I'm trying is as follows (I need some help with step 3):

1) Take a screen shot when the user clicks/touches the screen:

[image]

2) Apply edge detection:

[image]

**3) Extract the possible icon images around the Point associated with the user's cursor (Don't know how to do this)**

[image] [image]

There are easier cases in which the mouse-over event will highlight the icon/control, which allows me to identify the control with a simple screen shot comparison (before and after mouse-over). The above method is specifically for cases in which the icon is not highlighted. I'm new to emgu, so if anyone has any pointers on how to better achieve this, I'm all ears.

Cheers! Matt

Comment: I remember there was some API functions in Win98 to get the icon of an exe/link. May your target system have something similar?

Comment: Hey Chrono. That may be possible but the idea is to use image processing to make the process cross-platform and independent of any changes to the OS or device. Many of the windows API methods are no longer available on windows 8 since they've changed the way the screen renders. I don't think a system that depended on these methods would be very robust at the rate that operating systems and platforms are evolving.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing edge detection. Consider taking the following steps:

1. Only grab pixels which are within a certain radius of the point of the user's cursor. Create a new image with just these pixels.
2. Use [thresholding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_%28image_processing%29) to classify into foreground and background.
3. Calculate the centroid, (use mean x coordinate and mean y coordinate). Calculate deviation from the mean. Discard foreground pixels which are beyond a certain deviation from the mean. Eg: discard pixels that are more than 1.6 deviations from the mean.
   (You may need to experiment with this step ).
4. Use a [convex hull](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Convex_Hull_in_CSharp) to find the area of the image with the icon in it.